# Google App Engine library imports

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I've been experimenting with the Google App Engine, and I'm trying to import certain libraries in order to execute API commands. I've been having trouble importing, however. When I tried to  execute "from apiclient.discovery import build", my website doesn't load anymore. When I test locally in IDLE, this command works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the python api-client package comes with a command `enable-app-engine-project` that will install all of the required packages into your project folder:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/GoogleAppEngine

Comment: thanks so much. i can't believe this was what we were missing.

Comment: The link shows a redirect to https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine

Comment: If you download the zip from the project 'Downloads' page it will have everything you need, except for httplib2 which can be got from https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/

Answer (score 0):

The packages needs to be locally available, where did you put the packages, in the Python folder or in your project folder?